# CKEditor always add inline css 'font-size' and 'font-family' to source in CKEDitor

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

In the settings of CKEditor (ver 4.5.11) I have added a default font called 'Trebuchet MS' with a sizing of '16px'. I then save the value of the textarea in an database table.

Then when I want to use the html text saved in the table as the body of an E-mail. If I check the html saved in the table I get this html code:

```
<h1><em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, </em></h1>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<h3><em>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </em></h3>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><em>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </em></p>
```

The problem here is that if you send this by email, the emailprogram or website uses just a default font. 
Is there a way to always push something like:

`style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 16px;"`

Answer (score 0):

https://css-tricks.com/kinda-can-use-custom-fonts-html-emails/[enter link description here][1]

[1]: https://css-tricks.com/kinda-can-use-custom-fonts-html-emails/ ry this ......